# Selector background drawable changing color of parent

Tags: android, android-layout

I would like to achieve an effect where the background of one of my TextViews is changing on click. I'm achieving this via the drawable below with the state being pressed. I'm running into a strange scenario where if I pressed on the textview, drag away from it, then release my finger, the container background turns grey but the TextView background is white.

Somehow, the drawable effect is being transferred to the parent and causing this weird behavior. Tapping in other areas causes the parent background to change color (it should always remain white). Additionally, this layout is a header of a ListView.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/onclick_effect">

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/myPublicProfile"/>

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/5"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/dprEightyFive"
        android:background="@drawable/onclick_effect"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="start|center_vertical"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

drawable/onclick_effect

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:state_pressed="true">
         <color android:color="@color/grey_subtle" /> <!-- pressed -->
    </item>
    <item>
         <color android:color="@color/White"/> 
     </item><!-- default -->
</selector>
```

Comment: Try changing the android:layout_height="wrap_content" for textview id 5

Comment: Nope, still the same.

Answer (score 0):

in xml you can try

```
android:duplicateParentState="true"
```

Comment: I want the state of the parent unchanged. How would this do anything?

Comment: so create drawable for parent layout